# creating hyperlink using Linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, hyperlink

```
return (from doc in db.setupDocuments
                where doc.ParentDocumentID == parentId
                select new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Text = doc.DocumentTitle,
                    Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)doc.DocumentID),
                    LoadOnDemand = doc.setupDocuments1.Count > 0,
                    Enabled = true,
                    RouteName = 
                    //Url = "/Settings/SelectedItem?text=" + doc.DocumentTitle
                });
```

Hi friends i want to create a link on each object that is retrieved from the database. I want to forward it to the Action of the name of the object title (e.g. doc.DocumentTitle) and to a static controller "Settings". But not using the link like given in the commented line. When i use 
    ActionName = doc.DocumentTitle,
    ControllerName = "Settings"
it didn't work... Any suggestions. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the UrlHelper to generate links in an ASP.NET MVC application. For example controllers have the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url.aspx) property that you could use:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ...

    from doc in db.setupDocuments
    where doc.ParentDocumentID == parentId
    select new TreeViewItem
    {
        Text = doc.DocumentTitle,
        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)doc.DocumentID),
        LoadOnDemand = doc.setupDocuments1.Count > 0,
        Enabled = true,
        RouteName = Url.Action("SelectedItem", "Settings", new { text = doc.DocumentTitle })
    });

    ...
}
```

And if you need to use this in some other class you could pass an instance of the UrlHelper from the controller to it.

Comment: Well thanks for your reply but the problem is that the query is not written in some controller action it is in the Repository so there the Url.Action(..,..,..) is not accessible.
Is there any other solution????

Comment: In this case you could pass the UrlHelper instance as argument to the method that needs to use it.